# Can I git checkout from GitHub Desktop?

Tags: git, github-desktop

Is there a way to rewrite repository directory files to current branch state in GitHub Desktop?

Or can I only do it from command line with `git checkout mybranch`

and does GitHub Desktop keep all files of all branches in directory?

Comment: GitHub desktop, like SourceTree and many other similar tools, is merely a wrapper around Git running on your local computer, nothing more.  So, in general, anything you could do from command line Git you should be able to do in GitHub Desktop and vice-versa.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen wrong, they did not have tags implemented until version 2.5, see [Add and view Git tags](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4829#issuecomment-448441650).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will describe how to checkout on GitHub Desktop, which is equivalent to merging you current branch with the master branch. There are four steps you take(Branch names have been blanked out for privacy).

1. Go to the tab that shows the current branch.

[image]

2. Change the current branch to the Master branch.

[image]

3. Go back to the tab (now with master branch as current) and at the bottom click on "Choose the branch to merge with master".

[image]

4. On the screen that comes up chose the branch that you have been working on and click on merge with master.

[image]

These steps assume that you have pulled all the changes on the master into your current branch to avoid any conflict. If there are issues try to ensure that the branch you are working on has been updated by changes in the Master.

Comment: Merging changes the commit history: as the name says, it merges the sequences of commits from the two branches.

If you just want to view the files without changing anything I'd use t_huang's answer.

Comment: True that. I was writing to those needing the changes brought into a particular branch.

Answer (score 3):

To do `git checkout mybranch` on Github Desktop, you simply click on the dropdown menu on the upper left hand corner of the client, and pick the branch you want to switch to. It manages files exactly like git does, so all files are stored in their respective branches.